# How to stop loop string inside PHP loop with array

Tags: php, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm trying to stop `$implode_demographics` inside for loop below.

For example, if I use `echo $implode_demographics` inside loop, then I will get:

```
a01a01,a02a01,a02,a03a01,a02,a03,a04a01,a02,a03,a04,a05a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,b01a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,b01,b02a01,a02,a....
```

But If I use this string outside, then output works.

```
a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,b01,b02,b03,c01,c02,c03,c04,c05,c06,c07,c08,c09,c10,c11,c12,c13
```

[Online PHP test](https://3v4l.org/OgBaZ)

So, how I can `echo $implode_demographics` inside for loop to get same result?

```
$a_l_demographics = [11,3,13];
$a_p_demographics  = ['a','b','c'];
$a_r_demographics = [];
$c_demographics_values = array();
$a_c_demographics = min(count($a_l_demographics), count($a_p_demographics));

for ($i = 0; $i < $a_c_demographics; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $a_l_demographics[$i]; $j++) {
        $a_r_demographics[] = $a_p_demographics[$i] . str_pad($j, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $implode_demographics = implode($a_r_demographics, ',');
        // this won't work
        echo $implode_demographics;
    }
}

// this works
// echo $implode_demographics;
```

Comment: This loop is not designed very well and is very hard to follow. Please give us a bit more information about what is not working and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't works because you implode the same array again and again after you add data in it.

So in your first `echo` you have only `a01`, then you implode after with `a01` and `a02` value, etc.

Try to add `echo $implode_demographics . "\n";` and you will see that you have one var, then two, then three, etc. see example here : https://3v4l.org/WrCgJ

So if you want to `echo` each value INSIDE, just do :

```
<?php

$a_l_demographics = [11,3,13];
$a_p_demographics  = ['a','b','c'];
$a_r_demographics = [];
$c_demographics_values = array();
$a_c_demographics = min(count($a_l_demographics), count($a_p_demographics));

for ($i = 0; $i < $a_c_demographics; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $a_l_demographics[$i]; $j++) {
        $a_r_demographics[] = $a_p_demographics[$i] . str_pad($j, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $implode_demographics = implode($a_r_demographics, ',');

        // You echo only the last value
        echo $a_p_demographics[$i] . str_pad($j, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

        // If it's not the last loop : you add a `,`
        if (!($i == ($a_c_demographics - 1) && $j == $a_l_demographics[$i]))
            echo ",";
    }
}
```

This way you will `echo` only the LAST value each time and not all the value from the beginning each time, the output is :

```
a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,b01,b02,b03,c01,c02,c03,c04,c05,c06,c07,c08,c09,c10,c11,c12,c13
```

See code here : https://3v4l.org/MEnGe

Comment: @IncredibleHat you're right, I change my code thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's work, you have a problem with the implode. Implode d'ont put the glue (,) to the last value !
try this.

```
$implode_demographics = implode($a_r_demographics, ',');
echo $implode_demographics.', ';
```